# jax rs implementing paramconverter causes class loading exceptions

Tags: java, maven, jpa, jboss, jax-ws

I have a problem, when I create a class that implements ParamConverter I get errors deploying my persistence unit saying that the classloader cannot load the class that implements ParamConverter.

I have this line, and the project deploys properly and the unit tests run on Jboss:

`public class NamedEntityGroupParamConverter {//implements ParamConverter<NamedEntityGroup> {`

If I change this (and only this) it fails to deploy:

`public class NamedEntityGroupParamConverter implements ParamConverter<NamedEntityGroup> {`

Here is the error for hte latter code snipped above:

```
12:53:09,957 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#DefaultPersistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#DefaultPersistenceUnit": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: vfs:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/test.war/WEB-INF/classes/
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS011431: Could not load entity class 'net.mikeski.jpa_demo.entities.NamedEntityGroupParamConverter' with PersistenceUnitInfo.getClassLoader()
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.mikeski.jpa_demo.entities.NamedEntityGroupParamConverter from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:171)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is the dependencies of my `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
 -->        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the `resteasy` version on the server was 2, and the version I was using for my code was v3.

To fix, I downloaded `resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final-all` and extracted the jboss update file `resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.9.Final`.

Then, I changed into my directory that had jboss in it and went into the `modules` directory and unzipped `resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.9.Final`.  It overwrote a bunch of files and updated my resteasy version and it worked after that.